# Error enabling monitor mode using airmon-ng

Tags: airmon-ng

When I try to start monitor mode on my laptop, it just returns this:

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
  549 avahi-daemon
  614 avahi-daemon
  790 wpa_supplicant
  792 NetworkManager
 1163 dhclient

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp2s0      wl      Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

        (experimental wl monitor mode vif already enabled for [phy0]wlp2s0 on [phy0]prism0)
```

So then I use the check kill command like it suggests

```
sudo airmmon-ng check kill

Killing these processes:

  PID Name
  790 wpa_supplicant
17141 avahi-daemon
17144 avahi-daemon
```

Then I will try and use the airmon-ng start wlp2s0 command.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0

Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
17176 avahi-daemon
17182 avahi-daemon

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp2s0      wl      Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

        (experimental wl monitor mode vif already enabled for [phy0]wlp2s0 on [phy0]prism0)
```

However, my card is still not put into monitor mode.

I've updated my OS using

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

but it still refuses to enable monitor mode.

I have been able to start monitor mode before and haven't installed anything new or tried any other methods other than airmon-ng so I don't know what could have changed enough to cause these issues.

I've also never seen this before but I don't understand what it means and have a feeling that it's trying to tell me what the issue is:

```
(experimental wl monitor mode vif already enabled for [phy0]wlp2s0 on [phy0]prism0)
```

I have a Samsung Q330 running Ubuntu 18.04

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

My network card in the laptop is

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"[REDACTED]"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

prism0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

EDIT

Sorry, I used the wrong command for my network card

Here's the actual card information using lshw -C network

```
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: e8:39:df:26:dd:c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=172.20.8.105 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:24:54:ac:a3:c1
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc600000-fc603fff ioport:4000(size=256)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:bc:20:12:22
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

I also used "lspci -nn -d 14e4:" to get this information about the card I'm using:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it simply using `ifconfig`?

Take it offline: `ifconfig wlp2s0 down`

then into monitor mode: `iwconfig wlp2s0 mode monitor`

then put it back online: `ifconfig wlp2s0 up`

(Note: You will need sudo in front of all of these unless your running as root user which I really hope you are not)